# rendering an object from obj file and creating VBO results mix texture or black screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, vbo, wavefront

I want to render an object by parsing an obj file (android platform, opengl es 1.1). Parsing is OK and I have all data (v, vn, vt) and indices correctly stored in separate arrays. When I try to render using glDrawElements the object is drawn fine but texture is mixed. I guess it's because indices of texture coords are different with vertices and opengl only uses vertex Indices.
I tried to make a VBO to not work with indices. But this time when I call gldrawArrays nothing is drawn. (black page).
Please tell me what's the cause of problem and what's the other ways of rendering such objects.

Here is some parts of my code. If you need other parts, tell me.
This is class ObjectArr that holds the matrices and create VBO and draws the object.

```
public ObjectArr(float[] positions, float[] textureCoords, float[] normal, short[] faceIndices, short[] texturePointer, short[] normalPointer){
    texture = textureCoords;
    vertexPointer = faceIndices;
    normals = normal;
    vertex = positions;
    ByteBuffer ilbuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(vertexPointer.length * 8 * 4); // creating interleave
    ilbuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    interleave = ilbuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexPointer.length; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0;j < 3; j++) // positions
            interleave.put(vertex[3 * vertexPointer[i] + j]); // three number for position
        for (int j = 0;j < 3; j++) // normals
            interleave.put(normals[3 * normalPointer[i] + j]); // three number for normal
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
            interleave.put(texture[3 * texturePointer[i] + j]); // three number for texture
    }
    interleave.position(0);
draw (GL10 gl){    
    GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;
    int stride = 9 * 4;
    gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
    gl11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, stride, 0);
    gl11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    gl11.glNormalPointer(GL11.GL_FLOAT, stride, 3 * 4); // 4 is float size
    gl11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl11.glTexCoordPointer(3,GL11.GL_FLOAT,stride,(3 + 3) * 4);
    gl11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturesMatrix[0]);
    gl11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertexPointer.length);
    // deactivate arrays with gldisableclient...
    gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
public void createVBO(GL10 gl){ // creates VBO from interleave created before
    GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;
    VBO = new int[1];
    gl11.glGenBuffers(1, VBO, 0);
    gl11.glBindBuffer(GLES11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
    gl11.glBufferData(GLES11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * 4 * vertexPointer.length, interleave, GLES11.GL_STATIC_DRAW); // 9 is stride
}

public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) { // plane is a simple obj and also png file
    GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;
    // reading bitmap from raw folder
    gl11.glGenTextures(1, texturesMatrix, 0); // matrix with integer values for binding
    gl11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturesMatrix[0]);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

and this is unSurfaceCreated and onDrawFrame method in my renderer.

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) { 
    GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;
    obj.createVBO(gl);
    obj.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
    gl11.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  // Set color's clear-value to black
    gl11.glClearDepthf(1.0f);            // Set depth's clear-value to farthest
    gl11.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);   // Enables depth-buffer for hidden surface removal
    gl11.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);    // The type of depth testing to do
    gl11.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);  // nice perspective view
    gl11.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);   // Enable smooth shading of color
    gl11.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);      // Disable dithering for better performance
}
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl){
    GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;
    // Clear color and depth buffers
    gl11.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl11.glLoadIdentity();
    gl11.glTranslatef(-8.0f, 0.0f, -16.0f);
    //--- Touch
    gl11.glTranslatef(X, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl11.glTranslatef(0.0f, Y, 0.0f);
    //--- Touch
    gl11.glScalef(0.03f * zoomScale, 0.03f * zoomScale, 0.03f * zoomScale);  (NEW)
    obj.draw(gl);
}
```

I'm completely confused and stuck. I appreciate any help. tnx.